# I installed Brownie and after installation when i tried to see the version of it, i ran into this error, I am using MacOs 10.15.3 if that matters

Tags: python, bash, macos, blockchain, brownie

importError: dlopen(/Users/.../.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyGen_Send
Referenced from: /Users/.../.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/.../.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so

I tried pip uninstall recordclass and re-install it but couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python and don't know if this is the right solution, but I was getting the same error and upgrading cytoolz to version 0.11.2 seems to have worked for me:

```
pip3 install cytoolz==0.11.2
```